# Does choline bitartrate react with hydrochloric acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

Choline hydroxide is a base and reacts with HCl to form choline chloride salts and water.

I am wondering if choline bitartrate can also neutralize HCl. In case it doesn't, is there any other cheap form of choline that does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HCL is a stronger acid so it will displace the bitartarate forming choline hydrochloride and tartaric acid